# Is there an android call to check for corrupt java heap (even if from C++)?

Tags: android, heap-corruption

I'm getting some corrupt heap messages when running on specific devices with recent Android versions. The specific heap varies between runs, so my guess is that there is code that has a stale pointer and is writing over memory.

This only happens on occasion but my guess is that the heap corruption has occured before it appears.

One of the best patterns I've used on other systems is to use some call or other that checks the integrity of the heap - asking the heap if it is corrupt. I'd like to do the same here. Is there a suitable call I can make?